# Find maxima and minima within data and append True/False to corresponding row - Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, minmax

I want to find swing high and swing lows in stock market data. I want to be able to append each point to a column. Ex.) Have a column for isHigh and isLow that lines up with the Close price column. So each day that goes on, if the price is not a swing high or low, it will return False in the isHigh/isLow column. If it is a swing high or low, it will return True.

I have been able to find maxima/minma or turning points in stock market data, but all it returns is the number of turning points or the number of each point.

I'm having trouble extracting the actual points in reference to price.

I've used numpy and scipy argrelextrema.

````
```  
import matplotlib
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 
#Generate random data.
data_x = df['close']
data_y = df['close']
 
#Find peaks(max).
peak_indexes = signal.argrelextrema(data_y.to_numpy(), np.greater)
peak_indexes = peak_indexes[0]
 
#Find valleys(min).
valley_indexes = signal.argrelextrema(data_y.to_numpy(), np.less)
valley_indexes = valley_indexes[0]

**peak_indexes and valley_indexes only returns a numbered list of the points in numerical order.**
---
````

and I've tried.

````
close = df['Adj Close']

def turningpoints(close):
    dx = np.diff(close)
    return np.sum(dx[1:] * dx[:-1] < 0)```
````

**This returns a number 646, which is the amount of peaks and valleys in total**

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow"). In order for us to help you, it is necessary that you provide a minimal reproducible problem set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and all relevant code necessary to reproduce the example. What you have provided falls short of this goal. Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set. See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: Thank you for the insight @itprorh66, I will do that next time. I was able to figure out my question, so no need to. update now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take advantage of the fact that `rolling` with `window=len(df)` and `min_periods=1` gives you an easy window up to the current point. Then just check if value is the `min()` or `max()` up to that point.

```
df["isHigh"] = ( df["close"].rolling(len(df),1).max() == df["close"] )
df["isLow"]  = ( df["close"].rolling(len(df),1).min() == df["close"] )
```

Example:

```
   close  isHigh  isLow
0      0    True   True
1     11    True  False
2      2   False  False
3     22    True  False
4    -55   False   True
5     44    True  False
6     43   False  False
7     44    True  False
```

Comment: Thank you @Noah. I was able to figure out what I was looking for but this is definitely helpful and a new tool to add to my belt. Much appreciated.